# Link still opens new window with preventDefault() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, preventdefault

I am using this simple audio player for a music website. It works just fine locally but not when hosted on the website.

Installed on the website the program still opens a new window when I click the other song. I am only a little experienced with JS and jquery and have tried changing e. to event. but that did not work. The JS is in script tags in the body, however, and not linked separately. Where do I put a console.log() function to test to see if the preventDefault() function runs?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Here is the script I am using for the audio player

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript>
 function audioPlayer(){
        var currentSong = 0;
        $("#audioPlayer-lk")[0].src = $("#playlist-lk li a")[0];
        $("#audioPlayer-lk")[0].play();
        $("#playlist-lk li a").click(function(e){
           e.preventDefault(); 
           $("#audioPlayer-lk")[0].src = this;
           $("#audioPlayer-lk")[0].play();
           $("#playlist-lk li").removeClass("current-song-lk");
            currentSong = $(this).parent().index();
            $(this).parent().addClass("current-song-lk");
        });

        $("#audioPlayer-lk")[0].addEventListener("ended", function(){
           currentSong++;
            if(currentSong == $("#playlist-lk li a").length)
                currentSong = 0;
            $("#playlist-lk li").removeClass("current-song-lk");
            $("#playlist-lk li:eq("+currentSong+")").addClass("current-song-lk");
            $("#audioPlayer-lk")[0].src = $("#playlist li a")[currentSong].href;
            $("#audioPlayer-lk")[0].play();
        });
    }

  audioPlayer(); </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap audioPlayer() function with $(document).ready() function like below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

audioPlayer();

})
```